# How to Update ShellTile's in a Loop

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, live-tile

I would like to be able to cycle through the ShellTile's that are pinned to the start screen and update the background images individually. My issue is that the Background color is not updating on the tiles properly. On a button click event, if the current `tileCount` is > 0, then loop through the tiles and update the colors. In my code I can see the loop working properly and the correct tiles being retrieved and updated, but on the start screen several tiles have the same background color and some tiles will be updated even when they weren't supposed to. I cannot figure out what the issue may be, but my code is below.

To note, `Settings.RecentTiles.Value` contains an ObservableCollection of tile uri's that were created based upon the DateTime in which the ShellTile was created, and I use the index of this to search for the correct tile to update.

Button Click Event

```
if (tileCount > 0)
            {
                string title = null;
                title = Settings.RecentTiles.Value[tileCount - 1];
                string tileParameter = "uri=Tiles_" + title;

                ShellTile Tile = CheckIfTileExist(tileParameter);  // Check if Tile's title has been used             

                if (Tile != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var LiveTile = new StandardTileData
                        {
                            BackgroundImage = background
                        };

                        Tile.Update(LiveTile);
                        tileCount -= 1;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error");
                    }
                }
            }
```

And my `CheckIfTileExists` method

```
private ShellTile CheckIfTileExist(string tileUri)
    {
        ShellTile shellTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(tile => tile.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(tileUri));
        return shellTile;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe because your tiles have similar URIs? Instead of Contains I would use Equals.

Comment: Ok, doesn't it look for everything in the `Contains` statement as an exact match?

Comment: I think this may be a bug, everytime I run through the code I specifically see the correct ShellTile Uri being updated, but more than one of the ShellTile's pinned will be updated.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a quick sample of how to use Equals in checking to see if a ShellTile is pinned?

Comment: I just noticed that I use == operator, here is my code to determine if tile is pinned: if (ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First(t => t.NavigationUri.ToString() == toPin.UriNav) != null)